# List Kentico 7 published pages

Tags: sql-server, kentico

I inherited a CMS with some pages that are hidden or archived with published pages beneath those and I'm trying to get a scope for pages that are available to be viewed that are linked via other pages in the site. I'm trying to distinguish between pages that have a "path" to them and those that are published but only directly accessible via URI.

Is there a SQL Query or report that I can run on a Kentico 7 CMS (or its database) to get a list of published "pages" and whether or not they're able to be accessed (i.e. if they're linked to other visible pages or if they're hidden behind other parent pages)?

I know I could use a site crawler, but I don't know if that will take into account pages that are hit via buttons or script or things of that nature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query should get you what you're looking for.

```
SELECT *
FROM View_CMS_Tree_Joined
WHERE (NodeLinkedNodeID IS NULL OR NodeLinkedNodeID <= 0)
    AND Published = 1
```

What this is doing is querying the tree node view.  The NodeLinkedNodeID is the field which holds the linked page, if it is linked.  There are some other fields on that view you can query against but those two should get what you need.  You can also use the `DocumentIsArchived` field too, it's a boolean field.